# Python filter function usage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to understand how `filter()` function works in Python. Namely, Python 3. I know about list comprehensions, and they work as they should in my example, I just want to understand how `filter()` function works.

Suppose I have a list of integers I'd like to filter once, and then filter one more time:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myList = filter(lambda i: i <= 3, myList)
myList2 = filter(lambda i: i == 1, myList)
print(list(myList))
print(list(myList2))
```

The output is:

`[1, 2, 3]
[]`

Why `myList2` is empty? I know that `filter()` function returns a `filter` object, but isn't it iterable and allowed for use in subsequent `filter()` call?

If I change the code to

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
myList = filter(lambda i: i <= 3, myList)
myList2 = filter(lambda i: i == 1, list(myList))
print(list(myList))
print(list(myList2))
```

the output is:

`[]
[1]`

Why `myList` became empty after converting it to list explicitly in the 2nd `filter` call?